# Adding more upstream servers not working

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

My initial configuration of upstream block named "production" had the following configuration

```
upstream production {
            server 11.22.33.44 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
            server 4.5.6.7 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
            server 1.2.3.4 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
        }
```

Now I added 3 more servers and it changed to

```
upstream production {
            server 11.22.33.44 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
            server 4.5.6.7 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
            server 1.2.3.4 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
            server 9.8.7.6 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
            server 99.88.77.66 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
            server 19.18.17.16 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
        }
```

But now I see that I don't receive requests to the other three newly added upstream servers.

I tried to do the follwing commands and the new servers never get any response!

```
service nginx restart
service nginx reload
service nginx force-reload
```

What am I missing ? Do I have to add any other flag/variable to the nginx conf after adding new servers?

my nginx.conf file looks like

```
user www-data;
        worker_processes 4;
        pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

        events { worker_connections 1024; }

        http {
                sendfile on;
                tcp_nopush on;
                tcp_nodelay on;
                keepalive_timeout 100;
                types_hash_max_size 2048;
                server_tokens off;

                proxy_connect_timeout 60;
                proxy_send_timeout 60;
                proxy_read_timeout 60;
                send_timeout 60;

                server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

                include /opt/nginx/mime.types;
                default_type application/octet-stream;

                access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

                gzip on;
                gzip_disable "msie6";
                gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css text/comma-separated-values;
                upstream app_server {
                    server 55.44.33.22:8080 fail_timeout=0;
                }
                upstream production {
                    server 11.22.33.44 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
                    server 4.5.6.7 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
                    server 1.2.3.4 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
                    server 9.8.7.6 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
                    server 99.88.77.66 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
                    server 19.18.17.16 fail_timeout=0 weight=1;
                }

                include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
                include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
        }
```

I can directly curl into '9.8.7.6' and access the server but when I go through the nginx server, it gives a 404!

Answer (score 0):

So finally I was able to get to make this work by deleting the `default` file and then letting only my website.conf file to be present like  `/opt/nginx/sites-enabled/website.conf` and voila! I was able to get to my upstream server.

Hope this is useful for someone when they encounter this